# getting error Invalid NamespaceHandler class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler

Tags: spring

While running spring i am getting error that

```
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource 
[spring/tx-annotation-app-context.xml]; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class 
[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] 
for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with 
handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
```

Here is my file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>
    ....
</beans>
```

Here is the screen shot of my included jars

[image: spring jars]

What i am doing wrong with the namespace ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your using `spring-data-commons-core` version 1.1 and `spring-data-jpa` version 1.2.  Align the versions of these libraries.

Looking at a pom.xml file from one of my projects I see.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and it uses spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar

If you switch the packaging of `spring-data-jpa` to pom, it should download the necessary dependencies, then switch it back to `jar`.

Comment: What do you mean by align ? download other versions ?

Comment: My project uses spring-data-jpa 1.2.0.release and spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE, I'm guessing the versions of these jars is off in your project.

Comment: i have downlaoded teh 1.4.0 release and included the jar, also changed the aligning, but now i am geting error at line in my xml file `<jpa:repositories base-package="pk.training.basitMahmood.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />` that `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.` ?

Comment: @Basit make sure you have the jpa namespace included in your bean configuration file

Comment: I have these 3 namespaces in my file, you can see in my post too `xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"`, `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd`, `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa`. I have shuffle the declaration also, put `spring-jpa-1.0.xsd` before `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa` ?

Comment: @Basit Your post says your using `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd` not `spring-jpa-1.0.xsd` you need to be using 1.2.  I'm not sure where the .xsd from your comment was taken

Comment: Actually originally it was `spring-jpa-1.0.xsd`. I got the error, i saw that i am using the `spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar`. So i changed it to 1.2 to see if this removes the error. But nothing happen. Let me try with maven. May be i am collecting dependencies manually, so i am having these issues.