# Spring Data JPA - Error in RepositoryConfigurationExtension

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My task is to incorporate the Spring Data library, specifically its spring Repository implementation, into a legacy Java web application that uses Ant and Java 1.6 to build. I get the error about the "RepositoryConfigurationExtension" related to the Spring Data JPA namespace(stack track below). I used the following library dependencies:

```
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-core-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-data-commons-1.12.10.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-aspects-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-jdbc-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-data-jpa-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

I then configured the repositories in the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cc.spring.beans.persistence, com.cc.spring.beans.persistence.repository"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.cc.spring.beans.persistence.repository"/>

</beans>
```

This is the stack trace I received:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/beans/cycpersistence-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1225)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:229)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.call(Main.java:561)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.call(Main.java:557)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something? I cannot get rid of this error and move on to actually testing the incorporation of Spring Repositories. I am open to trying anything at this point. Thank you in advance!

P.S - I have looked at similar Stack Overflow questions, such as [getting error Invalid NamespaceHandler class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354112/getting-error-invalid-namespacehandler-class-org-springframework-data-jpa-reposi) and followed their suggestions. Unfortunately it did not work and that's why I am posting my own question.

**In response to Neil and to provide more insight on the problem, I have attached a screenshot of the class within the jar file, and confirmed it is on the classpath.**

[image: Spring RepositoryConfigurationExtension]

Comment: The missing class `RepositoryConfigurationExtension` should be contained in `spring-data-commons-1.12.10.RELEASE.jar`. Can you verify that this jar is on the classpath at runtime, for example by printing out the classpath? Also, please verify the jar actually does contain this class.

Comment: Jens, could you please post this as a separate answer so I can give you credit for the correct answer? The compile classpath was correct but NOT the runtime classpath. This was my first time using Jboss and I didn't realize that the Ant build file wasn't copying over the necessary .jar files. The repositoryconfigurationextension error is no longer there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing class `RepositoryConfigurationExtension` should be contained in `spring-data-commons-1.12.10.RELEASE.jar`. Verify that this jar is on the classpath **at runtime**, for example by printing out the classpath. Also, please verify the jar actually does contain this class.

Comment: Thank you Jens again. I hit another roadblock related to this same issue, could you please look at this question if you have a chance? Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335700/repositoryauditing-attributes-cannot-be-resolved-to-attribute-group-component

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [spring-data-commons-core.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core) jar file

Comment: Sadly same error, but thank you for the response Melad. I used the latest version, spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar