# repository:auditing-attributes cannot be resolved to a(n) attribute group component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Getting the Spring Data library, specifically Spring Repositories, into a Java legacy application(Java 1.6). The legacy application is using an Ant build as well and I am getting the following error when the Spring ApplicationContext is being loaded.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 43 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/beans/cycpersistence-beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1225)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:229)
```

Here are the Spring libraries I'm using, all versions outside of spring-data-commons-core.jar corresponding to the Hopper-SR10 release train from the Spring.io site. **All are verified to be on the classpath**

```
        <!-- New Spring, Spring Data, Spring JPA, Spring ORM Libs-->
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-core-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-data-jpa-1.10.10.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-data-commons-1.12.10.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-orm-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-aop-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-aspects-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-jdbc-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-beans-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-web-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-context-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-expression-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${compile.lib}/spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

Here is the Spring configuration xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
 ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cc.spring.beans.persistence, com.cc.spring.beans.persistence.repository"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.cc.spring.beans.persistence.repository"/>

</beans>
```

Previous Stack Overflow posts have mentioned that it can be due to incompatible spring Data jar files, but again I used the Spring release train to avoid that very situation. I have used different versions of the spring-data xsd schema in the xml file with no success. I have removed and added the spring repository xsd schema. Any and all ideas will be very appreciated in moving forward.

Comment: Indeed it sounds like some incompatibility between jars and Xml documents you are referencing. Why did you not post the start of the stack trace? Simplify your setup, until you can do the same thing with Maven. If it appears there to, post you complete configuration here. If doesn't fit into onw question, simplify further. If the Maven setup doesn't show the same behavior put breakpoints on various places of the stacktrace in both variants to learn what fails in the Ant version. It will probably point toward some misalligned version of  some jar.

Comment: Thanks Jens, trying that now. I also edited the initial post to have the full first line

Comment: Is the file you posted supposed to be the `cycpersistence-beans.xml` file that has issues? If yes: strange, it doesn't seem to have a line 43. Otherwise: please post that file.

Comment: Hi Jens, I believe it says line 43 because there are two other configuration xml files that are included as part of the application context. They were working before so I did not include them. 

The issue is solved, it boiled down to digging into the error. It couldn't find that attribute group so I looked up where it was located and it was in the   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd. I then dug into the jar file for spring data commons and found that it contained spring-repository-1.8.xsd. I specified that version and it worked!

Comment: If you feel that your original comment was the answer, I'll do like before and ask that you post it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: My comment is really just a comment. Your comment makes a better answer, so go ahead answer the question yourself.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you again Jens, your help truly means a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, it boiled down to digging into the error rather than just randomly trying answers to similar questions. It couldn't find the XML attribute group "repository:auditing-attributes". I then dug into the jar file for Spring Data Commons 1.12.10 and found that it contained spring-repository-1.8.xsd. I specified that version in the xml, cycpersistenance.xml, and it worked.

Look at the xsd to see where it is being referenced and where the error was coming from: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd

```
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:attributeGroup ref="repository:auditing-attributes"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And then the definition found here in http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.8.xsd. It is under the complex group "repository